# VS 2019 VB.net Winform trying to modify an existing .rdlc but it wants to upgrade the format and then i get a definition of report invalid

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have a vb.net winform application.  It has been around for years.  I'm using VS 2019 community edition.  When i try to open the rdlc file it tells me that I need to upgrade the format.  I do that and then when i run the application i get an error that the definition of the report is invalid.  I've read where i need to install the extension  Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.  I have done that and i can go in see my report in the designer but it still won't run.

The exact error is

> An Error occurred during local processing.  The definition of hte report " is invalid.  The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services.  The report definition may have been created wih a later version of Reporting Services, or contain contet that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas.  Details:  the report definition has invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2015/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

i'm using an rdlc file so the vb app is using reportviewer to hit a local database.. no reporting service server is involved.

anyone have any ideas
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a poor workaround.  If i open the rdlc file in visual studio 2013 and let it upgrade the format.. then i can modify the report in the designer.  Save the rdlc and close vs2013.  then open the VS 2019 project and it will compile and run the report.  Not great.. but at least its working